# Unlocking the disk Enter passphrase:?

Tags: login-screen

I install Ubuntu and any Linux product for the first time, and right after the restart I got this message, please help, thank You!

Unlocking the disk Enter pass phrase: ?

Comment: Did you encrypt your hard disk? You have to enter the passphrase you've set at the installation process.

Comment: I re installed OS Ubuntu, and typed in the same password (don't know why id didn't work the 1st time) and now it's OK.
But thank You for your answer on my question!